# std::regex capturing group syntax errors

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, std

I've ran into some pretty weird behavior using c++11 std::regex-es.
It repeatedly thrown std::regex_error exceptions, with even the most basic tweaks in the contents of a capturing group, so I wrote up some test cases and checked each one, below are the results.

```
            #include <regex>

            std::regex reg;

1  error    reg.assign("[0-9]");
2           reg.assign("[0-9]", std::regex_constants::extended);
3           reg.assign("[0-9]*", std::regex_constants::extended);
4  error    reg.assign("([0-9])", std::regex_constants::extended);
5  error    reg.assign("([0-9]*)", std::regex_constants::extended);
6  error    reg.assign("a([0-9])", std::regex_constants::extended);
7  error    reg.assign("a([0-9]*)", std::regex_constants::extended);
8           reg.assign("[0-9]+([0-9]*)", std::regex_constants::extended);
9           reg.assign("[a-z]+([0-9]*)", std::regex_constants::extended);
10          reg.assign("a(.*)");
11          reg.assign("a(.*)", std::regex_constants::extended);
```

I understand ECMAScript grammar(default) doesn't support the [0-9] syntax, but the extended grammar does, so my question is:

Why don't 4, 5, 6 and 7 work, if 8 and 9 do?

update #1:

the default grammar, ECMAScript does support it (thanks [Neil Butterworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2100815/neil-butterworth)), I only got that idea from the tests I tried.

Comment: Seems to [work for me](http://rextester.com/ODZ5710)

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: "I understand ECMAScript grammar(default) doesn't support the [0-9] syntax" - yes, it does.

Comment: gcc x86 64bit | 
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4 | 
with QtCreator | 
/home/<username>/Qt5.4.0/5.4/gcc_64/bin/qmake

Comment: Regex support in libstdc++ was *extremely* broken until not so long ago, the version shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 probably was still a bad one.

Comment: gcc 4.8? known to be buggy as hell. Move to v6 or 7 immediately!

Comment: There's always [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) as an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

"Regex support in libstdc++ was extremely broken until not so long ago, the version shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 probably was still a bad one."
– [Matteo Italia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214671/matteo-italia)

"gcc 4.8? known to be buggy as hell. Move to v6 or 7 immediately!"
- [Richard Hodges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2015579/richard-hodges)

Thank you!